# "sudo composer" command works but "composer" is not?

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php, osx-yosemite

This is going to be easy one I guess. On my OS X - Yosemite I have copied composer.phar to my `/usr/bin` directory. I have been using it for a while but today I needed to run "`composer update`". It didnt work of course so I ran "`sudo composer update`". Then I got the message "command composer not found". Chmm

I copied composer to `/usr/local/bin` according to the documentation and now "`sudo composer`" works like charm. BUT when I run "`composer`" without sudo, it still uses the old one in "`/usr/bin`" directory. So I deleted it.

Now composer works only with sudo command. I get "Could not open input file: /usr/bin/composer.phar" otherwise. What should I do to point command "`composer`" to the new location in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: How about permissions? Do `stat /usr/bin/composer.phar`

Comment: What is the output of `which composer`?

Comment: `which composer` outputs `/usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: 2msfoster: I deleted it there. Now I have only one composer at /usr/local/bin/composer.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod +x composer` (where "composer" is you file). This should make is access to everyone.

Comment: @Tomáš Votruba I've come across this issue as well and it's a pain to have to change the vendor folders owner/permission from `root` to `www-data`. I've tried as you suggested on `/user/local/bin/composer` and changed the owner and permissions on the composer file to `www-data` and I still have to run sudo first before any composer commands???

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative to get a nice composer command instead of composer.phar:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

> /etc/bashrc

Add this to that file:

> alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer"

run:

> source /etc/bashrc

Composer should now run without sudo.

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I encountered issues of having to run composer commands with `sudo` as well, but in order to get it working without throwing this kind of error (in Ubuntu 15.10):

```
[ErrorException]
copy(/home/randomuser/.composer/cache/files/barryvdh/laravel-cors/056068736ff8f002514178e1416c7665732eaddc.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

What simply solved the issue for me is:

- Navigating to my *home* directory `$ cd`
- Changing the ownership of *.composer* with: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .composer/`
- Then `composer install` works smoothly.

> PS: this might be different for other situation.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i will answer you how i solve it in my Ubuntu 16.10 and you can compare yours 
my composer folder set in

```
/home/abdallah/.composer/
```

i only give this file the 777 permission so can be reached by any user group

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/abdallah/.composer/
```

and that is it 
i hope this helpful for you

Comment: Don't ever do this! Ever!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from other answers it seems the solution can vary depending on your system. This is how I fixed the problem on Mac 10.12.

My composer executable in */usr/local/bin/composer* had a different group than *~/.composer/* config and cache files.

`/usr/local/bin/composer  myusr admin
~/.composer/  myusr staff`

The primary group for *myusr* is *staff* so I changed the group for */usr/local/bin/composer* to *staff*.

`/usr/local/bin myusr$ chgrp staff composer`

Cache files that had been created when running composer as *sudo* in the past were still causing problems so I deleted those. Composer cache files are located here: `~/.composer/cache/`

If updating hangs during *composer update* for a project check/empty cache files in the *.composer* directory for the project.